# How can I prevent Minecraft from disconnecting me when I'm AFK?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On Minecraft, I have a good AFK machine set up, it's all lit up and covered so I don't die while in it. But there is a problem with it:

When I go AFK, I'd say about half of the time I come back and the screen says "Disconnected" or "Timed Out". This defeats the purpose of an AFK machine, because none of my things load whilst I'm disconnected.

I was wondering if there is a way to eliminate or at least reduce the amount of times that I get logged out while AFK?

*NOTE* In this situation where I go AFK I am on a multiplayer server.

Comment: Are you being kicked for being afk or just losing connection? If it's the latter, then there's probably not a lot you can do. If it's the former... You may be able to use a macro or something

Comment: "Timed out" means the server stopped responding for too long and you got kicked to prevent issues, but I assume you know that.

Comment: Out of question, isn't AFKing usually against most server rules.  Assuming you aren't playing on a private one.

Comment: What afk macine are you using, it may be a flaw with the design

Comment: A lot of "budget" servers kick players who go afk. Some go as far as requiring payment to have the "privilege".

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are getting kicked automatically because the server set a "Max AFK time before kick" , this should be relatively easy to solve.

Simply place a trapdoor in front of you and close/open it at the same time as you press <kbd>F11</kbd>.

<kbd>F11</kbd> toggles fullscreen, and if you exit fullscreen while holding a key Minecraft will for some reason not detect that you released the key. So basically you're gonna be constantly opening and closing a trapdoor and therefore you will not be kicked.

Comment: Some servers have more sophisticated afk player detection.

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer: I made this. I'm not advertising it, I just think that it can be useful for him/her.**

There is an application I released at github, which automatically clicks the button specified, preventing you from getting kicked.

http://github.com/ardaozkal/keyboardmasher/releases

[image: how to use]

Just pressing start should be enough to start avoiding afk kick.

Comment: It looks like v3 is not very compatible with Minecraft, due to F3 being a button used quite often in game (unless you can change that?). v2 should work fine though.

Comment: v2 and v3 has 1 difference= F3 hotkey. I might add an option to change that.

Answer (score 1):

if you hold down the right mouse button the take it out of your PC then it will keep pressing right automatically if you stand in front of a trapdoor you will not get kicked for being away

Answer (score -4):

If you're on a laptop, don't close the screen. That will cause you to get kicked.

Comment: There are usually settings in the operation system that allow you to change how closing the laptop screen affects the computer. By default, I think it's set to sleep the laptop, but you can also set it to turn the screen off (while the rest of the computer is still on and running at full speed).

Comment: This will prevent you from timing out, but not getting kicked. Leaving the laptop open and waiting a while will still kick you. Closing it simply cuts off your connection.